# insmod fails because off unknown symbol in the module

Tags: linux-device-driver

When I do an insmod of Kernel object.It fails because of some unknown symbols in that module.

But for some reasons, Its not showing me the symbols (which it says as unknown).

Anyways to find that ? Please advise.

Comment: The system log might contain the information about these symbols. Take a look at the corresponding records in `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/kmesg` or whatever file contains the system log on your system. There should be a message there about which exactly symbols were not found.

Comment: You propably looked at the output of `dmesg` after the attempt to insert the module had failed. Were there anything suspicious?

Comment: Thanks Eugene!! I digged it little deeper and the proc/Kallsyms also looked a good option to me, a quick comparison of EXPORT SYMBOLS in the source file and symbols actually exported as depicited by this file gives a better picture. It helped me solve the problem.

Comment: @Vivek27 It will be nice if you provide us a detailed answer.

Comment: @Vivek You can also get some help using `nm` tool. `nm -u /your/test.ko`. It will list you the undefined symbols of your kernel module.

Answer (score 1):

That can happen when your linux kernel and your modules have a mismatch.
Cases like you are doing an insmod into a different kernel version than the one which you created the module for.

Make sure you are running the kernel version upon which your module is created.
I assume you have used the wrong version of kernel headers. Try changing that.